# How do I adapt an animation to export to lottie?

Tags: lottie, figma

The animation is exported very crookedly and I think it's about the degrees of rotation of the figma.

How can I get a working animation in the lottie plugin?

Here is the link
https://www.figma.com/file/QJwaFo3BY0a8XeusMQsNS9/Loading?type=design&node-id=0%3A3&mode=design&t=TmKlm9snhyxM5ab7-1
to the figma with animation, run the first frame to see the animation (shift + space).

I am using the LottieFiles plugin to export.

I'm having a lot of problems with figma, but this combination of tools is something I'll likely be figuring out on my own for a very long time.

Thanks for any information and help!

P.S: You can read here https://lottiefiles.notion.site/Supported-features-fd9655b3289443518b352f45e0913e83 that lottie supports 360 as 179.9, I was using it before I read this but my animation didn't work the way I needed it to.

It worked jerkily instead of rotating smoothly.